# Shiny disabling the actionbutton for x seconds while exporting data to SQL DB

Tags: r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I have a handsontable with dynamic data and I am uploading it to the MSSQL DB with the sqlSave code with the Submit button in shiny.

However, I could bot find any function that will going to disable the actionbutton for lets say 10 seconds. I tried shinyjs::disable and withProgress, incProgress things but none of them worked.

Thank you,

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=....;database=...;trusted_connection=true')

 withProgress( 
 sqlSave(dbhandle, dat = some data), 
      tablename = "Budget_Tool", 
      rownames = F, append = T, verbose = T, fast = F, colnames = F, safer = 
      T), value = 1, 
      style = "notification", message = "Submitting, please wait..")

    --------------------
       actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary",
                    style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-
      color: #2e6da4; font-size: 20px;"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using hide and show;

```
 observeEvent(input$submit, {
  hide('submit', animType = "fade", time = 5)
asd <- as.data.frame(cbind(Department = rv$data[,2], Cost_Summary_Key = 
  rv$data[,1], Calculated_Budget = rowSums(rv$data[,3:14]))) %>% 
  left_join(CSK_Budget, c("Department", "Cost_Summary_Key"))

   asd <- asd %>% mutate(Deviation = (as.numeric(Budget_2017) - rowSums(rv$data[,3:14])))

   x <- c()

   for (i in 1:nrow(asd)) {

  if(asd[i,5] >= -0.05)
  {x[i] <- TRUE} else {x[i] <- FALSE}

}

moment <- substr(Sys.time(), 1, 10)
moment2 <- substr(Sys.time(), 12, 19)
personel <- input$userName


if( all(x))
{


  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=...;database=...._SQL;trusted_connection=true')

  withProgress( 
    sqlSave(dbhandle, dat = (cbind(melt(rv$data, na.rm = F, varnames = c(Department, Cost_Summary_Key), as.is = F), Year = "2017", 
                                   Time_Stamp1 = moment, Time_Stamp2 = moment2, User = personel)), 
            tablename = ".....", 
            rownames = F, append = T, verbose = T, fast = F, colnames = F, safer = T), value = 1, 
    style = "notification", message = "Submitting, please wait..")


  js_string <- 'alert("Succes!!");'
  session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', list(value = js_string))
  showNotification("Thanks, your response was submitted successfully!", duration = 5, type = "warning")
}
else {showNotification("Check Your Budget Items !!", duration = 3, type = "warning")}

odbcCloseAll()   
show('submit', animType = "slide", time = 1)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less straight forward when you integrate the disabling and enabling before and after the action function.

Here is a sample snippet:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI({
  shiny::fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
    actionButton(inputId = "start", label = "start")
  )
})

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  actionFunction = function(){
    shinyjs::disable("start")

    # Replace actual code instead
    withProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                   for (i in 1:15) {
                     incProgress(1/15)
                     Sys.sleep(0.25)
                   }
                 })

    shinyjs::enable("start")
  }

  # Run action function on button click  
  onclick("start", actionFunction())
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```